# Are Apache (httpd) server logs stored synchronously?

Tags: apache-2.2

Is storing the logs a blocking action? (Does the request block until logs are written)? Or are they asynchronous?

What happens if writing to the logfile fails, or just take a long time?

Answer (score 1):

Have not tested with Apache 2 actually, but with Apache 1.3 series I did hit the 2 GB log file limit size several time. At that point Apache stopped responding, so at least for old Apache the log access capabilities were crucial for Apache's operation.

If this is true even with Apache 2.x, it's possible to workaround by piping the logs to logger. That way logs are sent to syslog facilities.

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger" combined
```

If you can play around with your Apache server, try to block the access to log file while Apache is running: mount your log mount point read-only or chown the access rights away. See what happens.